# Using Retrofit 2, nodejs, expressjs multer for uploading files, file is getting uploaded but req.body() is null

Tags: node.js, express, retrofit, retrofit2, multer

Heres my retrofit code

```
   private suspend fun uploadNewFiles(
        context: Context, files: List<FileData>,
        productModel: ProductModel
    ): Response<ProductModel> {
       val part=MultiPartUtils.prepareFilePart(context,"file",files[0].uri)

      val fileName = "${productModel.p_id.toString()}-${productModel.p_nm}"
      val fileNameRequestBody: RequestBody = MultiPartUtils.createPartFromString(fileName)

      val folderNameRequestBody:RequestBody=MultiPartUtils.createPartFromString("products")

      
        return productAPI.uploadSingleFile(part,
            fileNameRequestBody,folderNameRequestBody)
    }
```

```
object MultiPartUtils {

    fun  createPartFromString(descriptionString: String): RequestBody {
        return descriptionString.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
    }

   fun prepareFilePart(context: Context, partName: String, fileUri: Uri): MultipartBody.Part {
     
        // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
        val file: File = FileUtils.getFileNew(fileUri,context)// FileUtils.getFile(context, fileUri)

        // create RequestBody instance from file
        val requestFile: RequestBody= file
            .asRequestBody(context.contentResolver.getType(fileUri)?.toMediaTypeOrNull())

        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.name, requestFile)
    }
}
```

Api code below

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("/products/upload-products")
    suspend fun uploadSingleFile(
        @Part ImageToUpload:MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part("fileName") fileName:RequestBody,
        @Part("folderName") folderName:RequestBody
    ): Response<ProductModel>
```

Nodejs code below
**Upload Controller**
exports.uploadSingle = async (req, res) => {
console.log("upload-1")
const uploadFile = util.promisify(upload.single('file'));
try {
await uploadFile(req, res);
res.status(200).send({message:"File Uploaded"})
} catch (error) {
res.status(401).json({message:"Error while uploading!"})
}
}

**Uploaders Multer**

```
   const multer = require('multer');
   const path = require('path');
   const fs = require('fs-extra');

   const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(req.body  ) **-- this is null**
        const { folderName } = req.body
        const path =  `public/images/${folderName}/`;
        fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true })
        cb(null, path)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const { fileName } = req.body
        cb(null, Date.now()+"-"+fileName + path.extname(file.originalname))
    },
    limits: { fileSize: 10000000 },
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|JPG|webp|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF|jfif|JFIF)$/)) {
          req.fileValidationError = 'Only image files are allowed!';
          return cb(null, false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
      }
   });

   const upload = multer({ storage: storage }); 



   module.exports = upload;
```

My file is uploaded in server as undefined folder with file name as currentdateandtime-undefined.
req.body is null...
Can anybody help me out as I have tried a lot and cannot find a solution after spending hours??

I tried

```
   fun  createPartFromString(descriptionString: String): RequestBody {
        return descriptionString.toRequestBody(`text/plain`.toMediaTypeOrNull())
    }
```

but still req.body is null